# Windows check for solutions does nothing after BSOD

Tags: windows-7, solution, bsod

I have BSODs relatively often on my new computer.

I remember, that my old computed was checking for solutions for BSODs and showing me some reports about them, for example, that some driver is guilty or that solution was not found at the time.

Now I have absolutely no outcome after checking for solutions.

First I have a dialog with the message:

"Windows has recovered from an unexpected shutdown", 
"Windows can check online for a solution to the problem"

and two buttons

"Check for solution",
"Cancel"

I am pressing "Check for solution" and next windows shows me a new window, saying

Windows is checking for a solution to the problem

with progress bar. After few moments this window just closing silently with no outcome.

My question is: why it can be so?
I emphasize, that the question is not about the reason of BSODs, but about the reasons online checking does not work.

My Windows is Windows 7 64bit prof russian genuine,
with 12Gb of memory.

Previously this computer had 2Gb with 32bit windows with the same effect. So neither 64bit nor bit memory guilty.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if its an Nvidia, ATi, or Creative XiFi drivers, the online check does report back with solutions. Else, it collects the data for further study. Also, within Action Center, any problems you submit and don't get a solution are collected. Mostly, the issues are new and unique and therefore, you might not get any official response before you'd actually have had solved the issue.

Comment: But I remember that it was reporting anyway, i.e. if it was not solution at the time, it was reporting that there is no solution. Isn't it true now?

Comment: I have just looked into Action Center and saw no any information about my BSODs. I have 4 of them already.

Comment: My guess is because of the new stuff (software/hardware). And honestly, it has been a while since i sent my last error report or submitted pending reports. But it still works here on our Windows Server 2008 x64 at office. It is required of us to submit the reports and maybe we always do the paid call to MS

Answer (score 0):

Why not set it to not reboot after a blue screen. Then, you have the BSOD info right on the screen and can investigate the crash code. Here are [instructions](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/topic74644.html) on how to do this.

You can also attempt to manually debug the memory dump created from a BSOD, by following [these instructions](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/topic176011.html).

Comment: I have reboot after BSOD turned off. Also I have BlueScreenView program and can see the data.

Comment: My question is why automatic check stops silently.

Comment: Apparently someone didn't like my idea and gave me a -1, not sure why.

Comment: At a guess, because the question is explicitly about the *online solution checking*, and *not* about how to diagnose a BSOD ("I emphasize, that the question is not about the reason of BSODs, but about the reasons online checking does not work"), and/or that the OP clarified in comments that your answer didn't address the actual question and you didn't update your answer accordingly. Not sure I'd have bothered downvoting your answer myself, but I can easily see why someone who's a bit more prone to criticism might do so.